# How to register singular key press

Tags: c#

I need to be able to press a key down and no matter how long it is held down for it only does the action once. I have tried using bools to keep track of the state but haven't had any luck.

```
bool downPressed = false;
int a = 0;

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
    downPressed = true;

    if (downPressed == true)
    {
       while(a == 0)
       {
            y += 100;

            a++;
       }
    }
}
```

This is my latest attempt. The aim is for when the down key is pressed it moves the object by 100px but only once every time it is pressed.

Comment: Why is there a `while` loop? What is `a`?

Comment: Rather than using a loop, it may be far better to use the `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, or `KeyPress` events to handle this kind of requirement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `downPressed` will equal `true` (and don't test booleans against `true`/`false`) in that `if` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an EventHandler to your KeyDown Event of the Application/Form and just do the

```
y += 100;
```

in there.

```
public void OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    y += 100;
}
```